# Display data from specific projects from the VersionOne rest-1.v1/Data

Tags: versionone

I am pulling the data below from the Rest database to display asset data related to “Project One”. Does anyone know what the correct syntax would be to display more than one project/specific projects/sub projects within a single URL? i.e where=Scope.ParentMeAndUp.Name='Project One'; 'Project Two'; 'Project Three'

http://versionone/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/PrimaryWorkitem?sel=ID.Name,ID.Number,Scope.Name&where=Scope.ParentMeAndUp.Name='Project One'

AmiK

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma to separate the filter term values instead of a semi-colon.

For instance, using your example:

[http://versionone/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/PrimaryWorkitem?sel=ID.Name,ID.Number,Scope.Name&where=Scope.ParentMeAndUp.Name='Project
One','Project Two','Project Three'](http://versionone/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/PrimaryWorkitem?sel=ID.Name,ID.Number,Scope.Name&where=Scope.ParentMeAndUp.Name='Project%20One','Project%20Two','Project%20Three')